# Browser is not respecting tabindex setting

Tags: html, accessibility, tabindex

I have been told by my boss to add `tabindex="1"` to the Accessibility link in our site footer so that it will be the first thing that someone who browses a site by keyboard can get to and read about the accessibility steps we take.

I have added `tabindex="1"` to the link which [you can see here](http://www.topshop.com), but the browser doesn't seem to respect it at all (tested in Chrome/FF/IE 11). There are no other `tabindex` attributes on the page that I can see, so surely it should get picked up as the priority by the browser.

There are access keys used on the page, could this throw it out in some way?

I am sure it is something really fundamental, but I can't see what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce on FF ESR 45.3.0, the first tab takes me to the link in the footer.

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome/FF as well. Btw., worrying about accessibility in combination with keyboard navigation, but then not having any focus style on the links so that the user could see where they actually are … big fail. That is the very first thing you should add, if you care about accessibility at all.

Comment: Your boss should know that jumping keyboard users to the bottom of the page before presenting any content is a terrible idea and will have a seriously negative impact on the accessibility of the site.

Comment: Thanks guys, i know the site is a mess accessibility wise but we are moving to a new platform in the very near future and re-building from the ground up where accessibility will be a major consideration. For now we're just papering over the cracks till then.

Comment: Without delving into the page source and looking at all the javascript going on, I'd say if it's not working on a tab key press, perhaps there's a keyhandler somewhere on the page that calls preventDefault and stopPropagation that may be preventing the tab key press event from performing its intended function. Might be worth a look on your part?

Comment: For me the URL redirects to my.topshop.com which DOES NOT have the tabindex you mentioned. Are you sure your page wasn't redirected?

Comment: This isn't a direct answer so I'm just going to put this in a comment. Stating on your accessibility page that "This site has been designed and constructed to the W3C's WAI accessibility AA rating" is pretty dangerous for you legally. The site clearly doesn't conform to AA, and you're a big enough brand for this to be an actual concern if someone were to sue.

Answer (score 5):

It works for me, but as a long-time accessibility advocate I'd like to help persuade your boss it's a bad idea.

To see it working I suspect you are on a Mac and you need to [enable keyboard navigation](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200906/enabling_keyboard_navigation_in_mac_os_x_web_browsers/). People who need that would typically have it on already.

However, the reasons that adding a positive tabindex are not helpful include:

- Someone using a keyboard (or keyboard equivalent device) and can see the screen will be confused. They press tab and suddenly end up at the bottom of the page, then flip back up to the top. Combined with the lack of focus visibility, this will be very difficult to cope with.
- Someone using a screenreader will probably not notice the tabindex to start with because the main way of navigating is with 'arrowing' (using up/down to go element by element). However, if they are in the content area and press tab to skip to the next link or form control, they will suddenly go to the bottom of the page. Very confusing.

So in summary: Adding a positive tab index on a link in the footer will negatively impact the people it is supposed to help.

Here are the [appropriate ways to use tabindex](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2014/08/using-the-tabindex-attribute/).

There are quite a lot of obvious accessibility issues on the site, I'd recommend getting some advice.